# How remove attribute fields when creating a new product?

Tags: product, attributes

i want to remove attribute fields when creating a new product.kindly give me the steps to remove that things according to the https://prnt.sc/kp0ici .

Comment: You want to remove those for new products but do you want these for products when edit?

Answer (score 2):

It's a default feature available in Magento2.x to manage attributes.

> **Steps:** 
>   1. Go to Dashboard: Store->Attribute Sets
>
> 2. Select "Default" attribute set from the list, since as per your screenshot it was the attribute set selected
> 3. from "Groups" set select the attribute which you want to remove and drag that one from mouse to "Unassigned attributes" list on right
>      side.

After that save and you are done.